# ng-repeat on td element

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have item collection and I want to display each item object inside it in a table.

I have an image to display for each item as well. 
To do so, i decided to use `< tbody ng-repeat>`, with that, 
each image can occupy 3 rows cell

The issue comes when i need to display calculations in another column, which is an array object reside for each item.
you can see it [here](http://jsbin.com/nifazanehe/3/edit?html,css,js,output) http://jsbin.com/nifazanehe/3/edit?html,css,js,output 
with background color red.

the first two index of calculations object is hard coded and the rest is using ng-repeat. It solves the problem yet it looks buttugly! i hate it!

any suggestion?

other solutions i can think of :

to nest a table so i can do ng-repeat for that individual row 
or maybe just a simple
`< ul>< li ng-repeat>`
after empty out that section of rows and columns using rowspan and colspan

Comment: please put little code as well in the question

Comment: there is jsbin link there 

http://jsbin.com/nifazanehe/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: it is difficult to read thru complete code pls point specific fragments in the question

Answer (score 1):

you can work with np-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end directive

```
<table>              
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="demo in vm.demoArray">
      <td >{{demo.attr1}}</td>
      <td>{{demo.attr2}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
      <td>{{demo.attr1}}</td>
      <td>{{demo.attr2}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```